# Cannot clone from aws code-commit repo. Repo is "not found"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit, git-for-windows

I'm having problems cloning from an AWS CodeCommit repo.

As far as I can see, I've done all of the nescessary setup steps.

- I've created the repo
- I've created the git credentials
- I've done the following to configure git...

  - git config --global credential.helper "!aws codecommit credential-helper $@"
  - git config --global credential.UseHttpPath true
- I've confirmed that the version of aws cli I have works with credential-helper
- I've confirmed that my cli environment has access to my aws account, and can see my repo when I run the following command...

  aws codecommit list-repositories

However, when I try to clone the repo, it immediately returns with...

```
fatal: repository 'https://git-codecommit.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/[my-repo]' not found
```

It doesn't prompt for credentials.

If I try to curl the repo URL directly, I can see that it's returning a 401, which presumably is correct.

```
git version: 2.26.2.windows.1
aws cli version: aws-cli/2.0.17 Python/3.7.7 Windows/10 botocore/2.0.0dev21
```

I'm trying to do this in powershell on Windows 10 Pro.

Any thoughts about what might be going wrong?

Comment: any success since then? I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me
You need to change aws profile to account where repo is created:

In windows it can be done with:

```
setx AWS_PROFILE your_profile
```

After that you need to config git with credentials helper

```
git config --global credential.helper '!aws codecommit credential-helper $@'
```

Now you should be able to clone your repo